# This error pops up in ther OUTPUT tab when runnig and pressing a button : TypeError: Error #1006: removeListeners is not a function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

when pressing on a button that error comes up in the OUTPUT tab

the file is in the link

[Error #1006.rar](http://www.mediafire.com/?81ds33od3ywdc23)

This is the navigation_actions code where are the codes of the navigation bar (the buttons)

```
var buttonArray:Array = new Array( );
var currentButton:Object = new Object;

var navContainer:Sprite=new Sprite  ;
addChild(navContainer);

var navArray:Array=["من نحن","المحتوى","المراجع","التواصل", "خريطة الموقع"];

for (var i:Number=0; i<5; i++) {

var navItem:NavItem = new NavItem;
navItem.x = navItem.width*i;
navItem.nav_name.text = navArray[i];
buttonArray.push(navItem);
navItem.addListeners();
navContainer.addChild(navItem);

navItem.name = String(i);

navItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);
}

function onNavClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {

currentButton.y = 0;
currentButton.addListeners();
currentButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);

currentButton = evt.target;
currentButton.removeListeners();
currentButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);

}

initialNavigation();

function initialNavigation():void {

buttonArray[0].y = -10;
currentButton = buttonArray[0];
currentButton.removeListeners();
currentButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);
}

var navSide:NavSide = new NavSide;
navSide.x = navContainer.width;
navSide.width = stage.stageWidth - navContainer.width;
navSide.alpha = 0.7;
navContainer.addChild(navSide);

navContainer.y = stage.stageHeight-67; }
```

and this is the navItem actions (the buttons it self)

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;

nav_name.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
nav_name.selectable=false;

nav_name.x=170-nav_name.width+25;


function onOver(evt:MouseEvent):void {

TweenLite.to(this, 0.4, { y:-10});
}

function onOut(evt:MouseEvent):void {

TweenLite.to(this, 0.4, { y:0});
}

function addListeners():void {

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onOver);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onOut);
}

function removeListeners():void {

this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onOver);
this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onOut);

}
```

Comment: Sounds like a pretty straightforward error. However, for some of us to help you, you have to provide source **in the question**. It's the middle of the work day for some of us, and sites like mediafire are blocked.

Comment: @SamDeHaan so how can i post a code ?!!

Comment: Add the code to the question. Copy paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded your file and from what I can tell you added a listener to your NavItem instance but the actual event comes from its child. That's why `event.target` is not equal to a NavItem.

Either use `event.currentTarget` or add `navItem.mouseChildren = false;` so NavItem's children will not grab clicks.

Next time please post code.

Comment: thnx it worked btw i'm sorry but i'm new to this website so didn't know how to paste a code